# How to do complexometry titration of calcium oxalate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration

My titration of  calcium oxalate with NaEDTA doesn't work. I need to calculate the ion calcium within my sample. My essay is to test anticalculi activity.

Why do I say I have problem? Because the colour keeps turning back to its initial colour (pink) *more than twelve times*. It's never ending and the titration end point is so premature.

In my preparation, I added HCl 0.5 M to my calcium oxalate so it dissolves. Calcium oxalate has very low solubility.

- First, I used EBT indicator and ammonia buffer. When i add the ammonia the solution became foggy and there's a precipitation within the sample.
- So I used substitution titration with Mg-EDTA (EBT indicator) = Still happens
- Then change the indicator to hydroxynaftol blue and calcon = Still happens (I don't use buffer with this indicator, only NaOH, but when I add NaOH it's became foggy again)

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be complexometric?

You could acidify the sample and do a redox titration of the oxalate with permanganate or dichromate. And since the amount of oxalate is the same as calcium, bob's your uncle.